# Chrome doesn't update the element's width at some condition, is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Chrome Version: 23.0.1271.95 m
Operating System: Windows 7 64 bit

Please check the test page in http://jsfiddle.net/CTdQd/2/ or source code blow.

In the page there is a parent div with style "display: inline-block; position: relative;" which has 3 children with different width and height. Only one of the children has a "relative" position , other two have "absolute" position. When switch the "relative" position among the 3 children, the parent div's height updates correctly but not width, its width doesn't change. It's OK in Firefox and IE. Is this a chrome bug?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
  <title>test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #wrap {
      border: 1px solid #F00;
      display:inline-block;
      position:relative;
    }
    .out {
      position:absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 600px;
    }
    .out.in {
      position:relative;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:600px;height:400px;border:1px solid #DFDFDF;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="item1" class="out in" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#0F0;">200*200</div>
      <div id="item2" class="out" style="width:300px;height:100px;background-color:#00F;color:#FFF;">300*100</div>
      <div id="item3" class="out" style="width:400px;height:300px;background-color:#DDD;">400*300</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p id="log"></p>
  <div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <input type="submit" id="test1" value="show1">
    <input type="submit" id="test2" value="show2">
    <input type="submit" id="test3" value="show3">
  </div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('input').click(function() {
            var parent = $('#wrap');
            $('.in').removeClass('in');
            $('.out').eq($(this).index()).addClass('in');
            $('#log').text('the parent div\'s width: ' + parent.width() + 'px, height: ' + parent.height() + 'px');
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in WebKit. I filed [WebKit bug 104872](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104872) for this.

Comment: Anybody know a workaround to force Chrome to update the width? It works if you use dev tools to change the display style on the inner div and then change it back. But would love to be able to force update in script.